# onChange react-select isMulti Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using react-select. According to the official documentation, I should use 'isMulti' to get more than one option.

This is the component I've created.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Select from 'react-select';

function SelectBoxMulti({
  name,
  options,
  isClearable,
  value,
  placeholder,
  handleChange,
  label,
}) {
  return (
    <Form.Group className='mb-2'>
      {label && <Form.Label>{label}</Form.Label>}
      <Select
        name={name}
        isClearable={isClearable}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        options={options}
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={value}
        isMulti
      />
    </Form.Group>
  );
}

export default SelectBoxMulti;
```

This is the form

```
const [listTalents, setListTalents] = useState([]);

const [form, setForm] = useState({
 talent: [
  {
    label: '',
    value: '',
  },
 ],
});

const getAPIListTalents = async () => {
 const res = await getData('/v1/cms/talents');
 const temp = [];
  res.data.data.forEach((res) => {
    temp.push({
     value: res._id,
      label: res.name,
      target: {
        value: res._id,
        name: 'talent',
      },
    });
  });
  setListTalents(temp);
};

const handleChangeTalent = (e, i) => {
  let _tempt = [...form.talent];
  if (e.target.name === 'talent') {
    _tempt[i][e.target.name] = e;
  }
  setForm({ ...form, talent: _tempt });
}
```

```
<SelectBoxMulti
  label={'Speaker'}
  placeholder={'Masukan pembica'}
  name='talent'
  value={form.talent}
  options={listTalents}
  isClearable={true}
  onChange={handleChangeTalent}
/>
```

When I try to run it, there's no value read in the form from console.log(form). I need help setting up the onChange for this select box to work as I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the wrong prop to the SelectBoxMulti component you have to pass handleChange instead of onChange. Also, you don't have to write your own logic and pass it to the onChange prop; it will be handled internally by the Select component

```
const [listTalents, setListTalents] = useState([]);


const getAPIListTalents = async () => {
const res = await getData('/v1/cms/talents');
const temp = [];
res.data.data.forEach((res) => {
    temp.push({
       value: res._id,
       label: res.name
    });
   });
   setListTalents(temp);
};


const handleChange = (e) => {
   console.log({ e });
};

<SelectBoxMulti
    label={"Speaker"}
    placeholder={"Masukan pembica"}
    name="talent"
    options={listTalents}
    isClearable={true}
    handleChange={handleChange}
 />
```